# How to copy document file from one site to another

Tags: file, sharepoint, copy, move

I am looking for an example where based on the title name with in the object model I want to copy a single file from one Document library to another. I have more than 2000 files and don't want to loop through to complete collection is there any simple way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method like GetDocumentByName to use. But when do you want to do this? If you want it triggered by a user, you can use a custom action on the document library and when it's triggered you know what item triggered it.

If you want it done by a job I guess you could create a hidden SPView on the library that filters on the title. I'm not sure it's a great solution, but it can be done at least.